# Is it possible develop an asp.Net application that creates events on Google Calender?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, api, google-calendar-api

I am working on a personnel asp.Net project that has some calender based events. What I am thinking is if I can sync those events to a user's google calender.

Is it possible to create an application that create events on Google Calender? Is there a kind of API for this and if yes, would I have some limitations?

Comment: check this URL : on this you get the actual code http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide_dotnet.html#CreatingEvents

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an API for it. check [This link](http://code.google.com/apis/calendar/data/2.0/developers_guide.html) I think what you're looking for is the following:

```
EventEntry entry = new EventEntry();

// Set the title and content of the entry.
entry.Title.Text = "Tennis with Beth";
entry.Content.Content = "Meet for a quick lesson.";

// Set a location for the event.
Where eventLocation = new Where();
eventLocation.ValueString = "South Tennis Courts";
entry.Locations.Add(eventLocation);

When eventTime = new When(DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(2));
entry.Times.Add(eventTime);

Uri postUri = new Uri("https://www.google.com/calendar/feeds/default/private/full");

// Send the request and receive the response:
AtomEntry insertedEntry = service.Insert(postUri, entry);
```

If you have the calendar you are updating set as public, or you invite the other people, then they can subscribe to your calendar and any updates you put will show up on their calendars